# Remove the top and bottom deciles of groups within data set in R

Tags: r

I have a data set similar to the data below

```
Type    Count
A   0.022496545
A   0.969600752
A   0.476144762
A   0.142649351
A   0.902891034
A   0.004099406
A   0.80460619
A   0.642014007
A   0.688212724
A   0.879709931
B   0.886410732
B   0.803057447
B   0.203613404
B   0.606411333
B   0.886645412
B   0.418132624
B   0.653509209
B   0.70379929
B   0.071641697
C   0.248229147
C   0.534882145
C   0.445638266
C   0.527329119
C   0.382053332
C   0.121013092
C   0.922702539
```

I would like to remove the top and bottom deciles of each of the groups A, B, and C for summary statistics but leave the data in this same format.

Comment: I have been able to use quantile to remove the top and bottom of the entire "count" column but cannot get rid of the top and bottom of individual groups

Comment: It is good form to include the code that you have already tried in your question and explain why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'Type', we `filter` the 'Count' values which lies between the `90%` and `10%` quantile level

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Type) %>% 
    filter(between(Count, quantile(Count, 0.1), quantile(Count, 0.9)))
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[between(Count, quantile(Count, 0.1), 
                            quantile(Count, 0.9))], by = Type]$V1]
```

---

Or the `base R` using this methodology is

```
df1[with(df1, as.logical(ave(Count, Type, FUN = function(x)
                 x >= quantile(x, 0.10) & x <= quantile(x, 0.9)))),]
```

Comment: the OP said top and bottom deciles.  Did you want 0.1 & 0.9?

Comment: Source: local data frame [2,309 x 13]
Groups: Type [24] and then it gives me the original table. Yes I wanted 0.1 & 0.9 I just changed that when I ran the code.

Comment: @G5W I think you are right..  Thank you for the comments

Comment: @akrun I now get a table that is smaller but only displays in the console. How would I make a df2, from df1, that contains the new trimmed data?

Comment: @B.Mack  You can just assign `df2 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(Type) %>% 
    filter(between(Count, quantile(Count, 0.1), quantile(Count, 0.9)))`

Answer (score 2):

A base R alternative would be to combine `findInterval` and `quantile` to get the deciles with `ave` for grouping.

```
df$decGroups <- ave(df$Count, df$Type, 
    FUN=function(i) findInterval(i, c(-Inf, quantile(i, probs=c(0.1, 0.9)))))
df$decGroups
 [1] 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 3
```

`ave` operates on `df$count`, and splits by `df$Type`. The function applied to each type, first calculates the values of the top and bottom decile using `quantile` and then indicates these observations using `findIntervals`.

With the output, you can see that you want to keep all the elements with 2.

```
df <- df[df$decGroups == 2,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your initial data is in a data.frame called "initialdata", where the first column is a factor variable, I would do:

a) two steps:

1º) remove 10% and 90% deciles from ***initialdata*** per each Type:

```
filtereddatalist <- lapply(X = split(x=initialdata, f=initialdata$Type),
                    FUN =  function(x){
decilesboundaries <- quantile(x[,2],probs=c(0.10,0.90));
return(x[which(x[,2]>=decilesboundaries[1] & x[,2]<= decilesboundaries[2]),])
}
```

)

2º) format filtereddatalist into ***finaldatamatrix*** (the initial format, Matrix I guess):

```
finaldatamatrix <- NULL; lapply(X = filtereddatalist,FUN = function(x) {
   finaldatamatrix <<-rbind(finaldatamatrix,x)
   })
```

b) or all together:

```
finaldatamatrix <- NULL;lapply(X = split(x=initialdata, f=initialdata$Type),
                       FUN =  function(x){
                         decilesboundaries <- quantile(x[,2],probs=c(0.10,0.90));
                         x <- x[which(x[,2]>=decilesboundaries[1] & x[,2]<= decilesboundaries[2]),]
                         finaldatamatrix <<-rbind(finaldatamatrix,x)
                       })
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach. First, I load the library and create the data table.

```r
# Load data table
library(data.table)

# Create data table
dt <- fread(text = "Type    Count
A   0.022496545
A   0.969600752
A   0.476144762
A   0.142649351
A   0.902891034
A   0.004099406
A   0.80460619
A   0.642014007
A   0.688212724
A   0.879709931
B   0.886410732
B   0.803057447
B   0.203613404
B   0.606411333
B   0.886645412
B   0.418132624
B   0.653509209
B   0.70379929
B   0.071641697
C   0.248229147
C   0.534882145
C   0.445638266
C   0.527329119
C   0.382053332
C   0.121013092
C   0.922702539")
```

Then, I group by `Type` and filter each group where `Count` is `%between%` the 10% and 90% quantiles.

```r
# Subset
dt[, .SD[Count %between% quantile(Count, c(0.1, 0.9))], by = Type]
#>     Type      Count
#>  1:    A 0.02249654
#>  2:    A 0.47614476
#>  3:    A 0.14264935
#>  4:    A 0.90289103
#>  5:    A 0.80460619
#>  6:    A 0.64201401
#>  7:    A 0.68821272
#>  8:    A 0.87970993
#>  9:    B 0.88641073
#> 10:    B 0.80305745
#> 11:    B 0.20361340
#> 12:    B 0.60641133
#> 13:    B 0.41813262
#> 14:    B 0.65350921
#> 15:    B 0.70379929
#> 16:    C 0.24822915
#> 17:    C 0.53488214
#> 18:    C 0.44563827
#> 19:    C 0.52732912
#> 20:    C 0.38205333
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>